# Imported external jar but still get "Cannot be resolved" errors

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I imported the external jar under Modulepath, following this [guide](https://www.javatpoint.com/selenium-webdriver-installation). but im missing some if compared with those [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReXZW.png) in the guide. Could it be the reason why im still getting these errors? If thats the case, how can i get those or where can i download individually and import it?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;  
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;  
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;  

public class First {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // declaration and instantiation of objects/variables  
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\limje\\JenAutomation\\chromedriver.exe");  
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();  

    // Launch website  
        driver.navigate().to("http://www.google.com/");  

        // Click on the search text box and send value  
        driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("javatpoint tutorials");  

        // Click on the search button  
        driver.findElement(By.name("btnK")).click();  


    }

}
```

[image: guide screenshot]
[image: full screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing this issue because you need to fix your buld class path.

Once you add your jar files using Right Click on project --> Properties --> Click on apply and close

[image]

2. Remove all imports from your project and hover over on a code  `WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` and click fix project setup. Once done then again hover over on Webdriver and import libraries into your solution.

[image]

3. Finally your project looks like below and you havee to run your application as an java application

[image]

[image]

Comment: would you kind enough to hit upvote button from your end